# Found an unexpected Mach-O header code : 0x72613c21 while generating ipa file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have added GPUImageFramework manually not through pod. As I am getting successfully build on my Xcode but, when I export that build through achieve then facing this error shown [in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8V91.png) and when I click on "show logs.." option then this opens in new window which displays some log files  [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CKxd.png)

And I searched a lot and found that "remove it from Embedded Binaries" but if I remove it from Embedded Binaries then getting lots of error related to GPUImageFramework.

So please give me suggestion or a way that how to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the answer solve the problem? I have the same problem and a valid certificate on https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is after compiling, then regenerating your certificates should solve the problem.

Comment: I created a certificate but still get the error. I'm using Swift.